# How to stop spaces in url showing %20?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, spaces

If we look at a specific page the problem is occuring:

```
http://www.completeofficechairs.co.uk/RH%20Extend%20220
```

Where there are meant to be spaces, its showing %20.

So instead of `http://www.completeofficechairs.co.uk/RH%20Extend%20220` its meant to be:

```
http://www.completeofficechairs.co.uk/RH Extend 220
```

How do I stop this?

Im on an apace web server, so could it be a htaccess mod?

Comment: I don't think that's even possible. Spaces are not allowed in an address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use spaces or replace them with underscores `_` or dashes `-`. Your url will look better and be human-readable:

```
http://www.completeofficechairs.co.uk/RH-Extend-220
```

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not allowed in URLs. They have to be escaped (their escape character is %20). I don't think there is any way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Umm you can avoid that wierd %20 by replcing %20 with %09 but it will give tab space instead of space but which is not a perfect solution but can replace %20.Hope that helps